# Memory leak from pointers in Fortran

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, fortran

I have simplified my code here. There is a memory leak in the code, when I do not DEALLOCATE the POINTER, which is logical. But, the problem is that I cannot DEALLOCATE the pointer. Nullifying also results in memory leak.

```
PROGRAM pointer_allocation_deallocation
  USE, INTRINSIC :: IEEE_arithmetic, ONLY: IEEE_selected_real_kind
  INTEGER,     PARAMETER :: pReal      = IEEE_selected_real_kind(15,307)
  INTEGER :: istat
  INTEGER(pReal), DIMENSION(:,:),   ALLOCATABLE, TARGET :: trgt1  
  INTEGER(pReal), DIMENSION(:,:), POINTER :: ptr1  

DO i = 1,1000000
  ALLOCATE(ptr1(100,100), STAT=istat) 
  WRITE(*,*) 'istat1 = ', istat

  ALLOCATE(trgt1(10000,10000), STAT=istat)
  WRITE(*,*) 'istat2 = ', istat

  ptr1 => trgt1

  DEALLOCATE(trgt1, STAT=istat)
  WRITE(*,*) 'istat3 = ', istat

  ! DEALLOCATE(ptr1, STAT=istat)
  ! WRITE(*,*) 'istat4 = ', istat
ENDDO

ENDPROGRAM pointer_allocation_deallocation
```

Comment: A good general rule of Fortran is don't use pointers, use allocatables as they are much less dangerous. What are you really trying to do? There may well be a "more Fortran" way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You created the memory leak with the statement `ptr1 => trgt1`, because you lost anyway to access the memory that was previously pointed to by `ptr1`.  You should deallocate `ptr1` before this assignment statement.